org.slf4j.Logger no se publica valor en consola
Estoy desarrollando la siguiente clase para Java Versión 8:
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Utilidades {
    
    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Utilidades.class);
    
    public static String fecha(Boolean horaInicial, boolean esAyer) {
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        if(esAyer) {
            localDateTime = localDateTime.minusDays(1);
        }
        
        String pattern = "";
        if(horaInicial) {
            pattern = "00:00:00";
        } else {
            pattern = "HH:mm:ss";
        }
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'" + pattern);
        
        String date = localDateTime.format(formatter);
        log.info("slf4j");
        return date;
    }
}

El problema es que la línea de log.info("slf4j"); no me imprime el valor en la consola de eclipse. Me gustaría saber si debo poner alguna configuración en un fichero properties o en el servidor (utilizo WAS9).
Utilizo la siguiente configuración en el fichero logback.properties:
# Configuración del logger de SLF4J
    
# Define el nivel de log para la aplicación
logback.rootLevel=INFO
    
# Define el appender de consola
logback.appender.console=org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(org.slf4j.Logger.class)
    
# Define el patrón de formato para los mensajes de log
logback.appender.console.layout.pattern=%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n

y el del fichero logback.xml:
<configuration>
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
      <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
      </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="INFO">
      <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>
</configuration>


¿Como agregas slf4j? Agrega el contenido de tu pom.xml, tal vez no estás agregando las dependencias necesarias

@Jorgesys no es un proyecto maven. He agregado la dependencia el jar slf4j-api-1.7.36. Actualizo publicación el contenido de los fichero logback.properties y logback.xml
